# links open in new tab instead of frame after logging out of web app

Tags: html, frames

i'm an amateur and have a decent understanding of html, but i know very little about php, cgi, asp, java, etc. that is why i chose html/frames template for my site.
 I've read the article "framesareevil", but i just don't know any of the other, preferred, languages.

here's the situation:
 I've got a simple site with 3 frames top, menu and content.
I've got all the links in menu to open in content. this works fine to a point.
one of the links is to a web app (commit crm web interface)
the link open in the frame just fine, and i can do all my work etc. the problem arises after i log out of the web app. 
after logging out, all the links in menu open in a new tab. this is in all browsers on windows, Linux and android.
I have to reload the site to get the frames to behave like i want.

i set that logout page to auto redirect to the content default page (content.html), thinking maybe the web app was screwing up the frame or something, but it made no difference.

i do not understand when links open in a new tab after I've used the web app, and the content frame has been redirected to content.html

any thoughts?